# in Javascript I cannot get a global variable to update

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called myStr and inside a function I want to take str1 and store the content into myStr

See code:

```js
var myStr = "GoodDeeds";
alert(myStr); // results are GoodDeeds

// str1 receives a parameter from code "BadDeeds"
function startUser(str1) {
  myStr = str1;
  alert(myStr); //results are BadDeeds
}

alert(myStr); //results now are back to GoodDeeds
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. as I have not found the answer on Google.  All it tells me is I am doing everything right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never calling the function. Did you call it? Look how you should call...

```js
var myStr = "GoodDeeds";
alert(myStr);
// [results are GoodDeeds]
// [str1 receives a parameter from code "BadDeeds"]
function startUser(str1) {
  myStr = str1;
  alert(myStr);
  // [results are BadDeeds]
}
alert(myStr);
// call the function with BadDeeds:
startUser("BadDeeds");
alert(myStr);
// Should give BadDeeds.
```

Here, you have to understand the flow of information... There are four alerts.

1. The original `GoodDeeds` is alerted.
2. The first alert outside is alerted with `GoodDeeds`.
3. You call the function and the alert inside is alerted with `BadDeeds`.
4. Again, after the function call, the value of the original string is alerted as `BadDeeds`.

I hope you understood this.

**Final Note:** The results will be changed only after the function call and not before function call.

**Updated Snippet with Two Buttons:**

```js
var myStr = "GoodDeeds";

function startUser(str1) {
  myStr = str1;
  alert(myStr);
}

function alertStr() {
  alert(myStr);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertStr(); return false;">Alert String</button>
<button onclick="startUser('BadDeeds'); return false;">Change to BadDeeds</button>
```

I hope the above new snippet helps you to understand, it has actually changed. And JavaScript has both Synchronous programming model and Event Driven programming model.

Comment: Yes it is called from an onclick event.  that is were "BadDeeds" comes from

Comment: @Kerry Are you alerting after the `onClick` event, then after that, the value **will** be changed to `BadDeeds`.

Comment: @Kerry: *"Yes it is called from an onclick event"* This event/call happens **after** you call the last `alert(myStr);` in your code example. Maybe this helps with understanding callbacks (which applies to event handlers as well): https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: Order is as follows  pageload defines myStr  onclick calls startUser with the parameter of "BadDeeds"

Comment: @Kerry Yes, after the call, if you try to alert, maybe use a button or something, you will be able to see it change. I have updated the answer with two buttons, one to alert the value and one more to change. Please check.